# Can a class point to itself in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class in C#, let's say:

```
  public class COUNTRY
  {
      COUNTRY * neighbor;
      string countryName;
  }
```

C# is complaining that it can not point to itself (error code: CS0208)

This is allowed in C. For example:

```
typedef struct country
{
    struct country  *neighbor;
    char[50] countryName;
} COUNTRY;

COUNTRY unitedNation[]
{
   {COUNTRY a, "US"},
   {COUNTRY b, "ABC"},
   {COUNTRY c, "XYZ"},
   {0,""}
}

COUNTRY a
{
  {0, "Mexico"},
}

COUNTRY b
{
   {0,"Findland"}
}

COUNTRY c
{
  {0, "Australia"}
}
```

The structure defines a country with its neighbors.

unitedNation is a collection of many countries.

To simplify the issue, let's assume, a country can only have 1 or no neighbor. The variable of type COUNTRY could be easily initiated in C through declaration.

Does C# have similar ability?

Comment: [You don't make it a pointer `*` in C#.](https://ideone.com/YSZ9aa)

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko: That's right! But is there a way to declare and initiate the variable like C does?

Comment: No, you can't do this, and you should never need to because you should *never* use a pointer in C#

Comment: In `C#` class instance variables and fields are always references, so in `COUNTRY neighbor;`, `neighbor` is already a pointer (a reference) without the `*` there. Having class instances refer to other instances of the same class like this is of course allowed - otherwise trees and many other data structures would not work.

Comment: C# is definitely not complaining about a self reference, your code gives 2 errors: `CS0214 Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context`; and `CS0208 Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('COUNTRY')`. The description of CS0208 is clear. COUNTRY is a managed type so you can't declare a pointer to it. You simply want `COUNTRY neighbor;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes are (usually) reference types. As such, you create instances with `new` and when passed around in function calls, they are passed by "reference" (a fancy word for pointer). In contrast to reference types, there are also value types, which are passed by value, respectively.

So, what you try to do does not require special syntax.

```
using System;

namespace slist
{
    class SList {
        internal SList Next {get; set;}
        internal SList() {
            Next = null;
        }
        internal SList(SList head) {
            this.Next = head;
        }
        internal int V {get; set;}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            SList head = new SList();
            head.V = 1;
            head = new SList(head);
            head.V = 2;
            head = new SList(head);
            head.V = 3;
            IterateSList(head);
        }
    
        static void IterateSList(SList head) {
            SList current = head;
            while (current != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0:D}", current.V);
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Classes are *(usually)* reference types ? Can you pleas clarify what you mean?

Comment: The usually comes from the fact, that (at least in F#), you can use attributes to change some aspects of a type. `[Struct]` or something like that. As for what a reference type is, I explained it. Its like a pointer. And c# classes are reference types.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov a reference is like a pointer in C but more restrictive. You can't move in the memory adding os subtracting an amount of sizeof(Type) as you do in C. But when you set the variable, you are making a copy of the variable address, the object is in the heap and all your variables point to that memory address.

Comment: I am not trolling anyone. You can look up the C# documentation to see what reference types and what value types are. And you can read up on boxing of value types to make them reference types and you can read up on attributes. C# struct are value types, btw.

Comment: In C you have access to pointers and memory address easily. In C# you have classes (reference, pointer, heap) and structs (values, in stack) but you may have a struct in the heap (a field of a class, boxed, array items...). The important thing is that either in the heap or stack, is a value type and works like a value type (you copy the content, not the address)

Comment: @Victor In c#, you also have (since C# 9) Records, which are kind of immutable structs which are reference types...

Comment: @BitTickler Don't you have `record class` now too?

Comment: @Ray I switched to F# a few years back and did not follow up on C# since nearly a decade. Eventually they will have everything and their dog, I guess ;)

Comment: @BitTickler Everything but templates (sigh) :(

Answer (score 1):

First, define your class:

```
public class COUNTRY
{
    public COUNTRY neighbor;
    public string countryName;
}
```

Now, try this sample:

```
COUNTRY c1 = new COUNTRY();
c1.neighbor = c1;
c1.countryName = "Spain";

COUNTRY c2 = new COUNTRY();
c2.neighbor = c1;
c2.countryName = "France";

c1.neighbor = c2;
```

You can create `c1` and set the neighbor reference to `c1` itself. It's a non sense because Spain it's not a Spain neighbor but it's your "pointer", you can auto reference to this.

I create after a `c2`, for France country, and set Spain as a neighbor.

Finally, I fix Spain neighbor, setting `c2` (France).

I C#, when you use a class (not a struct), your variable is like a C++ pointer, it's a reference. In `c1.neightbor = c1` you are setting the variable neightbor to the address of `c1`. If you change `c1.neightbor`, you really are changing `c1`.